# Angular.js html5 file upload to grails controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, angularjs, grails

I would like to have the files that are dropped in this angularjs html5 upload example at JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/danielzen/utp7j/

uploaded to a backend by a grails controller.
While trying to accomplish this I created a simple grails controller:

```
class UploadController {

    def index() {

        if (request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest){
            for(filename in request.getFileNames()){
                MultipartFile file = request.getFile(filename)
                String newFileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + file.originalFilename.substring(file.originalFilename.lastIndexOf("."))
                file.transferTo(new File("/home/myuser/temp/$newFileName"))
            }
        }

        render "ok"
    }

}
```

Then I open an ajax XmlHttpRequest2 POST to the grails controller:

```
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/app/upload")
```

but the grails controller cannot cast the request to MultipartHttpServletRequest,
probably because this ajax way of invoking the grails controller is not using the multipart/form-data way of uploading.
I tried setting the header on xhr for enctype multipart/form-data to no avail.

I'm completely stuck at the moment and would like to know how I can process the uploaded files in the grails controller

Comment: Look inside `params` whats in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I traced the POST request that was generated by the XmlHttpRequest.send(formData) call with the built-in Chrome Developer Tools. 
To my surprise the request method was not of type POST with enctype=multipart/form-data but of type OPTIONS.

This hint got me on the right track and with the help of Google I found out that this OPTIONS request happens as a preflight check as per-spec defined by CORS.

From wikipdia:

> Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows
>   JavaScript on a web page to make XMLHttpRequests to another domain,
>   not the domain the JavaScript originated from.[1] Such "cross-domain"
>   requests would otherwise be forbidden by web browsers, per the same
>   origin security policy. CORS defines a way in which the browser and
>   the server can interact to determine whether or not to allow the
>   cross-origin request.[2] It is more powerful than only allowing
>   same-origin requests, but it is more secure than simply allowing all
>   such cross-origin requests.
>
> The CORS standard works by adding new HTTP headers that allow servers
>   to serve resources to permitted origin domains. Browsers support these
>   headers and enforce the restrictions they establish. Additionally, for
>   HTTP request methods that can cause side-effects on user data (in
>   particular, for HTTP methods other than GET, or for POST usage with
>   certain MIME types), the specification mandates that browsers
>   “preflight” the request, soliciting supported methods from the server
>   with an HTTP OPTIONS request header, and then, upon “approval” from
>   the server, sending the actual request with the actual HTTP request
>   method. Servers can also notify clients whether “credentials”
>   (including Cookies and HTTP Authentication data) should be sent with
>   requests.

Because my grails (tomcat) server was running from localhost:8080 and my html/javascript was running from within the WebStorm IDE on its built-in http server on localhost:63342, the XmlHttpRequest was effectively CORS, because different port numbers on the same host are also considered cross-origin.

Thus, I needed to make sure that the Grails (tomcat) server allowed this, and I was able to do this with the excellent cors plugin for Grails which can be found at https://github.com/davidtinker/grails-cors

After that the request was recognized as a `MultipartHttpServletRequest` and the file could be fetched from `params`

Answer (score 0):

Taking a peek at the network when doing the upload from the fiddle you get:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarygZi30fqQLB2A9qAC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadedFile"; filename="file.txt"
Content-Type: text/javascript


------WebKitFormBoundarygZi30fqQLB2A9qAC--
```

I believe then you'll get an "uploadedFile" as the param key into Grails, so you could write a controller action like:

```
def uploadFile(CommonsMultipartFile uploadedFile) {
    ///accessing the file data: uploadedFile.bytes, uploadedFile.contentType, uploadedFile.originalFilename
}
```

To be sure what is being passed do a debug on the params map that the action receives and change the action method parameter name accordingly.

Comment: That's what would be expected, but I ran into an issue because of CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) with the XmlHttpRequest. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body ng-controller="FileUploadCtrl">
 $scope.selectedFile=[]; 
                      $scope.onFileSelect = function ($files) { 
                            $scope.uploadProgress = 0; 
                            $scope.selectedFile = $files; 
                        }; 
                        $scope.myData = {}; 

                      $scope.upload = function(){ 
                            var formData = new FormData(); 
                            formData.append("file", $scope.selectedFile[0]); 
                            formData.append("data", myData.message.value); 
                            $http.post('api/upload', formData, { 
                                transformRequest: angular.identity, 
                                headers: { 
                                    'enctype': 'multipart/form-data', 
                                    'Content-Type': undefined 
                                } 
                            }) 
                            .success(function(){ 
                                alert("done"); 
                            }) 
                            .error(function(){ 
                                alert("failed"); 
                    }); 


</body>

<form ng-submit="upload()" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myData">       <div>

    <textarea  rows="3" name="message" placeholder="Send Message"></textarea>               
          <input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" /> 
        </div> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">upload</button> 
        </form>
```